# Cumulative Updates Numbering

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

In a SharePoint 2013 Farm I have a patch level at 15.0.4701.1000 but when I search for this cumulative update I cannot find an exact matching number - closest I can find is 15.0.4701.1001 (note the 1001) & this seems to be from March 2015.

Where do I find the cumulative update corresponding to 15.0.4701.1000?

Reason is that I'm trying to build an environment that is patched exactly to the same level for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust the Version number from the central admin, because that is configuration Database Version.

better way to look for the patch, **go to Central admin > Upgrade & Migration > Check product and patch installation status**  if the March CU's KB number listed here then simply download the March CU and apply it to the server.

*Specificly for March CU, KB listed 1001 but actually it is 1000.

Check these blogs to understand it.

[Common question: why does the version number on the "Servers in Farm" page not change after installing October CU?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/10/23/common-question-why-does-the-version-number-on-the-servers-in-farm-page-not-change-after-installing-october-cu/)

[SharePoint patching demystified](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/08/19/sharepoint-patching-demystified.aspx)